# Extract encoded strings based on percentage symbol with Regex and Java

Tags: java, regex

I am trying to to detect/match encoded chars starting with `%`.

My Regex is `([%][2-9|A-F][0-9A-F]{1,2})+`

On regexr.com it works and it matched what I need.

I used these strings for tests: `caf%C3%A9+100%+noir%C20` and `test%C3%A9+%C3%A0+100%`

In my Java code it is returning only the first group.

```java
String pattern = "([%][2-9|A-F][0-9A-F]{1,2})+";
Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile(pattern ).matcher(input);
if (matcher.find()) {
  for (int i = 0; i < matcher.groupCount(); i++) {
    System.out.println(matcher.group(i));
  }
}
```

And the output for `caf%C3%A9+100%+noir%C20` is `%C3%A9` and not `%C3%A9` + `%C20`.

For `test%C3%A9+%C3%A0+100%` is `%C3%A9` and not `%C3%A9` + `%C3%A0`

Comment: Side note: you don't use a `|` character inside character classes unless you actually want to match the character '|' literally.

Comment: You can actually get the matches without a group `(?:%[2-9A-F][0-9A-F]{1,2})+`  https://regex101.com/r/khX9Mg/1

Comment: I believe you need to convert the `if` statement into a `while` loop. And you don't really need the `for` loop. You can just print `matcher.group(0)`. See [this demo](https://rextester.com/YIFNC23434). You might as well convert the capturing group into a non-capturing one: `(?:[%][2-9A-F][0-9A-F]{1,2})+`.

Comment: @41686d6564 thanks it works. You are right I should use a `while` loop :)

Comment: This looks suspiciously like you’re trying to reinvent [form URL decoding](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/net/URLDecoder.html).

Answer (score 2):

The Regex you are using is overly complicated. Also, the way you are trying to print all the matches doesn't work. Try this:

```java
String input = "caf%C3%A9+100%+noir%C20";
String pattern = "(?:%[2-9A-F][0-9A-F]{1,2})+";
Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile(pattern ).matcher(input);

while (matcher.find()) {
    System.out.println(matcher.group());
}
```

This prints:

```
%C3%A9
%C20
```

Comment: @Thefourthbird You're right, my mistake. So they need the repeating group. I corrected it. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Based on @41686d6564 comment, the solution is to use a `while` loop and `group(0)`:

```java
String pattern = "([%][2-9A-F][0-9A-F]{1,2})+"; 
Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile(pattern).matcher(input);
while (matcher.find()) {
  System.out.println(matcher.group(0));
}
```

Comment: Is there a reason why you put the `%` in a character class (`[%]`)?